# How to configure local cache for testing

Tags: c#, caching, azure, azure-worker-roles, shared-cache

I'm working with Azure shared cache. In the development process I need to write a lot of data which takes time.

**Is it possible to configure the worker-role to write to a local cache?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the new in-role cache? You can specify either a portion of your existing role's RAM for cache, or create a dedicated cache role. Either way, it would be running within your deployment. Assuming you colocate your cache with, say, your web role, then you'd effectively have a local cache.

Look [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/) to see a .net tutorial. Note that this cache can also be used with any other language; this just shows integration with Visual Studio (and it works the same in Eclipse).

Comment: And the good thing about the in-role cache is that it's supported in the emulator.